# Connecting to remote SQL Server in C#.Net

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, connection, database-connection, connection-string

I'm trying to connect to the database, and it keeps telling me "invalid instance".

Here's my code:

```
string connectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=server;Database=db;;Uid=user;Pwd=pass;";
OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection();
MyConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
MyConnection.Open();
```

What is the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using this.

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

And if you are using MS Sql server, better use with SqlConnection.

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connestionString)){
   conn.open();
   ..
}
```

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005